# Can't explain the formatting of this question

Tags: support, questions, review

I was running through the review queue of low-quality posts and came across this one.

[how to access json data through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715128/how-to-access-json-data-through-javascript)

Granted it isn't a very clear or good question, but it had some answers, so I thought rather than flag it I would just edit it and fix the grammar and formatting problems.  However when I clicked edit it looked different and didn't show up as if it should appear in a code block.  But for whatever reason it still is, can anyone explain what is going on here?

Here's another one exhibiting the same behavior: [how to call XML based web service through a blackberry eclipse JDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482100/how-to-call-xml-based-web-service-through-a-blackberry-eclipse-jde).

[Its source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/d8c90312-4b9e-4464-8b41-fc9a450d9248/view-source) looks like a plain paragraph, but before someone fixed it, it showed as a code block with a scrollbar:

[image]

It would be interesting to see what is the actual root cause of this, even though the solution is quite obvious as already pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, my question seemed quite silly when people just immediately fixed them and the edit history looks like they were always normal =).

Comment: Yeah, and also might have taken away the opportunity to get slightly more detail...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only guess at this, but it appears to me that there were some hidden (non printable) characters in there and that the edit was not significant enough (or was not detected as an edit) so was not applied.

After simply trying to delete the (non-existing) whitespace and saving the edit, I saw what you did (nothing was changed).

I made some extra changes (added a line break, changed the case of a letter and added a ?) and that seems to have sorted it.

Comment: Hmm, strange yeah it looks fine now.